# What does "soda" mean in places where it doesn't mean soft drink?

Tags: meaning

The title is pretty self explanatory.
"Soda", "Pop", "Coke", etc. all refer to the same thing in different parts of the world.

Where the word for soft drink is "soda", "pop" is a verb, and "Coke" is only a brand.

But what does "soda" mean in places where the beverage is called "pop" (or something else)?
Does it have any meaning at all?

Comment: Possible duplicate:   http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6926/which-is-correct-soda-or-pop

Comment: @Josh61: Most definitely not a duplicate.

Answer (score 6):

Soda is another name for plain carbonated water even in countries where soda is the generic term for Coke etc. However, it is usually called *club soda* in those countries to differentiate it.

Comment: And, depending on the context, it may also refer to things like *washing soda* (where, of all of the substances that have tradionally been referred to as *[something] soda* — whether that compound contains sodium or not — it's obvious that you mean only one of them).

Comment: I'll wait a bit before accepting since only a few minutes have passed, but your answer is good so if there aren't any more and I forget, feel free to ping me and I'll accept yours. :) Thanks!

Comment: The term _club soda_ was unknown to me until I visited the US. The term I know for carbonated water is _soda water_. _Soda_ on its own has several meanings, as bye says, but in context I would understand it to mean _fizzy drinks_.

Answer (score 5):

In the technical sense *soda* can also refer to sodium (bi)carbonate, and products derived from sodium compounds such as baking *soda*, caustic *soda*, etc. Incidentally, I believe this is where the usage of soda for a soft fizzy drink comes from, as sodium bicarbonate is used in the carbonation process to make fizzy drinks.

I would say that taken just on its own, *"soda"*, would still be recognised as a term for a fizzy drink such as Coke, even if was not the locally used term. Though in many areas it is frequently used to mean soda water (when used as a mixer), e.g. *a Lime and Soda*.

Comment: In the UK and Canada, *soda water* now has sodium bicarbonate as a flavouring, as a distinction from plain carbonated water.  Hence a *Whisky & soda*

Comment: +1 for some reason I didn't realize the connection between baking soda and drinking soda until you mentioned it, cool!

Comment: Soda water would traditionally from a [syphon](http://www.matthewclark.co.uk/productimages/00015252.jpg).

Comment: As someone who grew up in Britain watching _Kenan & Kel_ as a kid, I always associate _soda_ with sweet fizzy drinks. cf. "Who loves orange soda?" - "Kel loves orange soda!" Despite it not being a native meaning in the UK.

Comment: Baking soda is sodium bicarbonate; caustic soda is sodium hydroxide. Different stuff--do NOT take the latter in a glass of water for a stomach upset.

Answer (score 5):

When you're wondering about what a word means, the tool of choice is a dictionary. For example, according to *The American Heritage Dictionary of the English Language, 4th Edition*:

> **[Soda](https://www.wordnik.com/words/soda)**
>
> n. Any of various forms of sodium carbonate.
>
> n. Chemically combined sodium.
>
> n. See carbonated water.
>
> n. Chiefly Northeastern U.S., Eastern Missouri, & Southwestern Illinois See soft drink. See Regional Note at tonic.
>
> n. A refreshment made from carbonated water, ice cream, and usually a flavoring.
>
> n. Games The card turned face up at the beginning of faro.

Comment: The dictionary only tells me the meanings it *could* have, not which meanings actually dominate the usage in the general population.

Comment: @Mehrdad in which general population? Which country? Which dialect? Which age group? Which period? In any case, looking at a dictionary would have shown you the alternate meanings of thew word so when _soda_ does not mean _club soda_ the rest of its meanings stand. Which one is more common depends on the group of people you are talking about.

Comment: That could be in an answer of its own. I kind of expected a common definition irrespective of the region (aside from soft drink), so if there really isn't a single common secondary meaning then that's good information to put in an answer, and not something I'd find by looking at a dictionary.

Comment: @Mehrdad if you read the dictionary definitions I've pasted above, you'll see that the meaning of _soda_ to mean soft drink is actually regional and mostly confined to Northeastern U.S., Eastern Missouri, & Southwestern Illinois. Dictionaries _do_ contain that type of information. The common definition is "Any of various forms of sodium carbonate." which is why it is first in the dictionary entry. The secondary meaning is the one you consider primary.